# Why won't PNPUTILS pipe to FIND inside this FOR loop in windows CLI?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, pipe

My goal is to script a search for all drivers of a certain class (specifically "Unknown") in a windows installation. I've [read that DEVCON can do this](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/52741-install-unknown-devices/), but the goal is to use tools available out-of-box. In attempt to do this in the cmd prompt (versus in a batch file), I tried this command, and got the error shown:

```
C:\Users\user>FOR %A IN ('pnputil /e |find /i "printers"') DO (ECHO "foo")
| was unexpected at this time.
```

I know the `pnputil | find` portion is executing properly...

```
C:\Users\user>pnputil /e | find /i "printers"
Class :                     Printers
Class :                     Printers
```

... but I want to use a FOR loop, as the ultimate goal is to print the entire section for that driver. [Pseudocode is something like: FOR through all of `pnputil /e`, when `%line_in_question` contains `%my_string`, print the previous two lines, the line in question, and following two lines.]

Here's a snippet of the response from `pnputil /e`...

```
Published name :            oem1.inf
Driver package provider :   Microsoft
Class :                     Printers
Driver date and version :   06/21/2006 10.0.10586.0
Signer name :               Microsoft Windows

Published name :            oem0.inf
Driver package provider :   Microsoft
Class :                     Printers
Driver date and version :   06/21/2006 10.0.10586.0
Signer name :               Microsoft Windows
```

I'm guessing my syntax for the FOR loop or the code-substitution attempt inside the FOR loop is incorrect, but I've been unable to identify the exact location of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape the pipe in this case:

```
FOR /f %A IN ('pnputil /e ^|find /i "printers"') DO (ECHO "foo")
```

Because it is with higher prio than for command.And probably you'll need `/F` switch because you want to process a command.To filter only the printers will be harder though...

Here's a script that will show only items with class "printer" :

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set counter=0
FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A IN ('pnputil /e') DO (
 set "%%A=%%B"
 set /a counter=counter+1
 if !counter! equ 4 (
    if "!Class !" equ "                     Printers" (
        echo Published name #!Published name !
        echo Driver package provider #!Driver package provider !
        echo Class #!Class !
        echo Driver date and version #!Driver date and version !
        echo Signer name #!Signer name !
        (echo()
    )
    set counter=0
 )
)
```